# Adding extra fields when uploading image with CollectionFS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm new to programming in Meteor, I have been the whole day trying to figure this out without any luck.
I'm using collectionFS to upload an image, I want to give it my Meteor.userId(); so that only logged in users can see their own images
I have the following code:

```
'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    Imagess.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
      if (err){
         // handle error
      } else {
         // handle success depending what you need to do
        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
        var imagesURL = {
          "profile.image": "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id
        };
        Meteor.users.update(currentUserId, {$set: imagesURL});
      }
    });
 });
},
```

I tried doing this but it won't work, it says access denied:

```
'change .myFileInput': function(event, template) {
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
    Imagess.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
      if (err){
         // handle error
      } else {
         // handle success depending what you need to do
        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
        var imagesURL = {
          "profile.image": "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id
        };
        createdBy: currentUserId,
        Meteor.users.update(currentUserId, {$set: imagesURL});
      }
    });
 });
},
```

Any idea how can I get this done?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Metadata here, for example.

```
FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
     file.metadata = {
            imageOwner:Meteor.userId();
      }
    Imagess.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
```

Check out this little [DEMO](http://demo.fscollection.meteor.com) and here is the [Source Code](https://github.com/Ethaan/simple-uploadFS)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help.
I added that and am trying to display the images with:

`images: function () {
    return Imagess.find({'metadata.createdBy':Meteor.userId()}); 
    }`


but it won't return anything, any idea why?

Comment: and if you run the query on the `console` what you get? and `undefined`?  the metadata its actually there?

Comment: Already fixed it, forgot to add: `var newFile = new FS.File(file);` thanks a lot!